# How to throw a PDF with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, pdf

I've been working on an application that generates pdf files server sides. I use ajax for polling a server side handler and retrieve it when it's finished generating.

I'm almost done and I'm right at the end, now the silly thing is that an ajax call puts the entire pdf file into client memory, while really I just want to throw it to the user in the browser.

Trying the window.open() function to open a direct link instead of using ajax doesn't get past the popup blocker.

I saw other suggestions with using an iframe. If people are suggesting I'm having a window in my page that displays the pdf file, I can't do that. Only the save as dialog would suffice.

Comment: Just set `window.location.href` to the url of the pdf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `window.location.href` to the url of the pdf file?